# Tag for puzzles that can easily be presented on a whiteboard (or blackboard, or chalkboard, etc)

Tags: feature-request, tags, tag-synonyms

One thing I've been hard-pressed to find online is a collection of puzzles or riddles that can be easily presented on a chalkboard, blackboard, whiteboard, etc such as in a classroom or office. Essentially, these would be puzzles that can be presented and solved using a simple drawing or writing space and wouldn't take an impractically long time to write out whole paragraphs for the question.

Since the goal of puzzling stackexchange is to be a high-quality source for puzzles on the internet, it makes sense that we would want to provide a way for people to look up these types of puzzles. I've seen that we already have the [blackboard](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/blackboard) and [matches](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/matches) tags, which would be a subset of what I'm thinking of. Geometry-based ones like [this dots puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/2066/join-all-circles-together-only-with-6-lines) would also work. Many of the questions in the [letter-sequence](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/letter-sequence) tag would fit, but ones like [this one](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/42408/read-learn-live-escape) would obviously not fit on a normal whiteboard.

So my questions are:

1. **Does a tag like this already exist?**
2. If not, **would our site benefit from such a tag?**
3. If so, **what would we call it?** A name like [whiteboard] would probably cause too much confusion.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think this would count as a complete answer, but here's my shot.

> 1. **Does a tag like this already exist?**

No, I don't think so. You mention [blackboard](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/blackboard): nonetheless, all the questions tagged like this are also tagged [mathematics](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mathematics). If I understood correctly, you're looking for puzzles which are also not mathematical.

> 2. If not, **would our site benefit from such a tag?**

**I don't think so.** The problem is that I can see many, many puzzles (and tags) fit the description you gave:

- [number-sequence](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/number-sequence)
- [rebus](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rebus)/[visual](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/visual): [this one](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/11025/what-famous-line-does-this-linux-command-line-represent), [another example](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/33493/from-an-iq-exam-what-does-this-say) and [another one](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/30052/a-gloomy-rebus-with-many-outs)
- [lateral-thinking](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lateral-thinking): [An example](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/30607/which-country-is-india-in), [this very well-known one](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/24848/how-can-64-65), and [this one](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/31118/add-a-letter-to-make-this-true)
- [geometry](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geometry): [This example](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/2066/join-all-circles-together-only-with-6-lines), or [this one](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/22615/the-challenge-square).
- [pattern](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pattern): [An example](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/45659/where-is-it-moving-all-around-the-world), [another one](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/46449/increasing-and-decreasing) and [this one](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/18729/four-is-cosmic)
- [riddle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/riddle): some are very short, yet good: [this one](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/20233/a-short-brutal-riddle), [this one](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/44891/about-a-man-and-a-bee).
- etc.

**The problem is that if you want to create this tag, say, [whiteboard](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/whiteboard), I think this will be categorised as a [meta-tag](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/)**:

> Meta-tags are actually a subset of a larger problem that I usually call dependent tags. These are tags that don't say anything by themselves - you can't tell what the question is about unless they're paired with some other tag (or several of them). These tags are a problem because people don't realize this and will often use that as the question's only tag.

Although your idea of creating a "bank of puzzles which can be presented on a whiteboard" is good, in my opinion, we should not create a tag like this. I don't really have an alternative to offer unfortunately, the only one I can think of right now is for the users to look around on PSE :-).